# What is the optimal image ratio in which to merge JPEG files to reduce storage space?

Tags: python, image, opencv, jpeg

I'm trying to find the optimal way to combine small 8 by 8 pixel JPEG images into a larger JPEG file which occupies less disk space.

I have an image which I have split into various smaller images of 8 by 8 pixels, however I noticed that the total disk space occupied by the folder containing all of these smaller images was significantly higher than the disk space for the original image. Noticing this, I assumed that, inversely, combining smaller images into one larger image has the potential to occupy less storage.

I'm using OpenCV in Python, and I noticed that just reading and writing the image creates a new file which occupies more space than the original (I'm not sure why this happens either). However, I when I combined the smaller images into a vertical stretch which stacks all of the 8 by 8 pixels on top of each other, it occupied more space than when I left the image in its original dimensions. I was wondering if there was a way to determine how to merge the images in a way that the space occupied by the merged image is at minimum. It does not matter in what position each of the initial 8 by 8 images is in in the merged image or what the dimensions of the merged image are.

Here is the code to split an image into various smaller images:

```py
def save(path):
    img = cv2.imread('Images\\' + path)  


    max_ind = 1
    for i in range(0,len(img)-8,8):
        for j in range(0,len(img[0])-8,8):

            sections = img[i:i+8]
            save = []
            for section in sections:
                save.append(section[j:j+8])

            cv2.imwrite("Saves\\" + str(max_ind) + ".jpg",np.array(save))
            max_ind += 1
```

And here is the code I used to save an image in a way that all of its 8 by 8 pixels are stacked on top of each other:

```py
def save_master(path):
    img = cv2.imread('Images\\' + path)  


    master = []
    for i in range(0,len(img)-8,8):
        for j in range(0,len(img[0])-8,8):
            sections = img[i:i+8]
            save = []
            for section in sections:
                save.append(section[j:j+8])

            master.extend(np.array(save))

    cv2.imwrite("Saves\\" + "master.jpg",np.array(master))
```

Comment: 1. File systems have to allocate a certain amount of space to a file, so even if the file is 1 byte it might need 1kbyte or more of disk space. 2. Jpeg is a lossy format which is why large images can be ‘compressed’ to take less space on disk, but the compression does need some extra data, but with e.g. 10kbytes of raw jpeg data that overhead is small. However if image is only 8x8 pixels that overhead starts to dominate. Combining multiple 8x8 images into one lager JPEG risks that lossy compression affects (modifies slightly) each of the 8x8s. Try using a lossless compression like PNG.

Comment: You might try find a file format that can embed multiple images, like Windows .ico files can (I think) - but I’d still use lossless format for the 8x8s themselves (i.e. not JPEG).

Comment: When you read a compressed image into opencv, it expands it to full pixel size with e.g. 24bits/pixel so needs a lot more storage than the compressed image, but then you want to work on each pixel, so it has to uncompress it.

Comment: What is the point of this please? I mean what are you actually trying to do? How can it be useful to store 8x8 images in a bigger file if you don't know which is which? Can you provide some sample images please - or a big one with many 8x8 images that I can crop out to play with?